# SE-Accounts shows incorrect History answer count

Tags: bug, status-completed

Odd. My Stack Exchange - Accounts section shows my correct question count, but the answer count shows 0, not 1 answer as expected. History is the only SE site wherein I participate that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen certain stats that take time to update on the History site, like you though its the only one I have seen it in, has it ever updated later on?

Comment: The one answer I gave on History was on May 15, so 6-7 days now without an update.

Comment: Yeah, that would be excessive.  Although management of the site is under StackExchange while they may read these forums you might get better response if you send email to them directly or post on the SX support forums.

Comment: Ok, thank you @MichaelF .

Comment: I've noticed that as well.